# C++ include, using cplusplus {{ }} construct

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have encountered the following code recently and have trouble understanding it:

```
cplusplus {{
#include "Frame_m.h"`
}}
```

What's the meaning of `cplusplus {{  }}`?

Comment: What kind of file was this in?

Answer (score 4):

OMNet++ contains a language called NED which is used to write the programs. NED is more concentrated on event simulation than general purpose programming.

Now, if you want to use raw C++ types within NED, you surround them with the `cplusplus {{}}` construct to let NED know that they're of a different form. That's what you're seeing in your example, the construct surrounding an include of a normal C++ header.

See [here](http://www.omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp33/manual/usman.html#sec218) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of this is **"If you are compiling in C++, include Frame_m.h"**. However the correct sequence of statement should be..

```
#ifdef _cplusplus{
#include "Frame_m.h"
}
#endif
```

[this thread](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t318522-help-with-__cplusplus.html) can be useful for you,